# Copy of series in legend for prepared boxplot

Tags: pgfplots, legend

When I add a legend entry to a `boxplot prepared` plot, I get an identical copy of the box plot (which may be huge!) in the legend. How can I fix this? As a workaround, I am currently adding `area legend` to override the style of the legend image.

MWE below:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            boxplot/draw direction=y,
            boxplot/box extend=0.36450000000000005,
            xmin=0.5,
            xmax=1.5,
            legend style={
                legend pos=outer north east,
            }
        ]
            \addplot[
                fill=blue!50!white!50!white,
                draw=blue!50!white,
                forget plot,
                boxplot prepared={
                    lower whisker=0.47544910179640715,
                    lower quartile=0.4670588235294117,
                    median=0.45895953757225433,
                    upper quartile=0.45895953757225433,
                    upper whisker=0.1784269662921348,
                    draw position=0.7975
                },
            ] coordinates {};
            \addplot[
                fill=blue!50!white,
                draw=blue,
                boxplot prepared={
                    lower whisker=0.5753623188405796,
                    lower quartile=0.5631205673758864,
                    median=0.5591549295774647,
                    upper quartile=0.5438356164383561,
                    upper whisker=0.18859857482185272,
                    draw position=1.2025000000000001
                },
            ] coordinates {};
            \addlegendentry{Series 1}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting box plot with oversized legend entry]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the prettiest perhaps, but one could make a custom `boxplot legend` style and apply that to the `axis`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/boxplot legend/.style={
   legend image code/.code={
     \draw [|-|,##1] (0,2mm) --
         node[rectangle,minimum size=2.5mm,draw,fill,##1]{}
        (0,7mm);
    }
  }
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            boxplot/draw direction=y,
            boxplot/box extend=0.36450000000000005,
            xmin=0.5,
            xmax=1.5,
            legend style={
                legend pos=outer north east,
            },
            boxplot legend % <-- added
        ]
            \addplot[
                fill=blue!50!white!50!white,
                draw=blue!50!white,
                forget plot,
                boxplot prepared={
                    lower whisker=0.47544910179640715,
                    lower quartile=0.4670588235294117,
                    median=0.45895953757225433,
                    upper quartile=0.45895953757225433,
                    upper whisker=0.1784269662921348,
                    draw position=0.7975
                },
            ] coordinates {};
            \addplot[
                fill=blue!50!white,
                draw=blue,
                boxplot prepared={
                    lower whisker=0.5753623188405796,
                    lower quartile=0.5631205673758864,
                    median=0.5591549295774647,
                    upper quartile=0.5438356164383561,
                    upper whisker=0.18859857482185272,
                    draw position=1.2025000000000001
                },
            ] coordinates {};
            \addlegendentry{Series 1}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```